# How to use Modbus with Microchip PIC24

Tags: c, uart, modbus, microchip, mplab

First time using Modbus. I'm trying to send a request to read a temperature value from my slave device (ID is 0x01). I'm sending the command through UART and viewing command on my logic analyser. 
Here is my code:

```
void temp_sensor()
{

//Transmit RTU to Inisitu probe to fetch Temperature and units
Flow_Control_SetHigh();

unsigned char TempRTU[]= {0x01, 0x03, 0x00, 0x2D, 0x00, 0x02, 0x54, 0x02};

int i;
int data_len = 8;

for (i = 0; i < data_len; i++) {

    UART1_Write(TempRTU[i]);   
}  
}
```

0x01: Slave ID:
0x03: function code:
0x002D: Read temperature register:
0x0002: Read 2 registers:
0x5402: CRC Checksum:

The hex string is correct when viewing through UART on my analyser, however when setting the analyser to view Modbus, the string is not even close to being correct. I've attached a screenshot of my analyser while viewing the Modbus signal.

Has anyone got experience with Modbus and PIC microcontrollers? [image]

Comment: what happens in `Flow_Control_SetHigh()`

Comment: This drives the RS485 transceiver allowing me to send the string into the slave device.